# Is there a name for an "array with no holes"?

Tags: terminology, arrays

How would you call an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...] that has (and ensures) the property of not having any undefined values through all its length.

"Dense" could work but it's not exactly what I mean, as it has more to do with zero/non-zero values.

Comment: What about "initialized"? Let A be an array in which each element has been initialized. Let A be an array with no uninitialized elements.

Comment: Are you just looking for a generic term or asking if there is already a defined term. If general, Perhaps a "comprehensive array"?

Comment: If you think of an array as a function, an array with no undefined values is a total function. Just a thought.

Comment: (@Steven: there's a start, but what about *assigning undefined values* to elements later on? I read *no undefined*, not *no uninitialised*.)

Comment: @Pseudonym That's also how I see it, 'total' seems like a good choice for a word. Care to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard term for this, as it's very language-specific whether your notion makes sense, or what it would mean exactly. For instance,

- Some languages have no undefined values, or no undefined values in
  arrays, or only undefined values for certain data types. For instance, in C, you can cast an arbitrary piece of memory to an array of integers and then read integers from it without ever initializing the array; there is no way of inspecting an array value to determine whether it has ever been initialized. In C, there is no such thing as an undefined integer.
- Some languages, e.g., Perl, support sparse arrays: they not only have
  undefined values, but whole regions of the array may not have been
  allocated in memory.
- Some languages, e.g., PHP, distinguish between an array value not being set and
  it being set to the undefined value. Some, e.g. R, even distinguish between different undefined values.

How will your term apply to them?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure itself is unambiguously called a contiguous array. Depending on the context and language I would call it "initialized" or "having only non-null elements" or similar to describe the contents.

Comment: Thanks @orlp, I'm gonna go with the 'total' suggestion as 'contiguous' is more related to memory allocation than what I'm trying to convey.